# How to recover a lost file

Tags: c, vim, compiler-errors

I was trying to edit my CS project named obr.c, and when I compiled it, I actually typed "gcc -Wall -o obr obr.c " instead of "gcc -Wall -g obr.c -o obr". Now my program has disappeared from my directory! I can still run the program by typing "obr" and everything works fine. However "obr.c" is no where to be found! I have searched in all other directories just to see if it somehow moved. What is the solution to this?

Comment: `gcc -Wall -o obr obr.c` this is not the reason for your file `obc.c` to disappear.

Comment: If you have `set backup` in your vimrc. `backupdir` might have the file.

Answer (score 0):

The tools I know to make such things are :

- [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/)
- [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/)